# How to detect disconnect and reconnect for subscription(websocket) in apollo client

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, graphql-subscriptions

I am building a chat service and **I want to handle the cases when the subscription(websocket) connection is disconnected.**  Apollo client is configured like bellow. I removed unnecessary code like cache, authLink etc.

How do I do this with react, apollo client? If its disconnected, I would like to show that to the chat page and when the user reconnects, I would like to fetch all the missed chat messages. This is why I need to know the disconnect, connect events

Below are the relevant packages used in this app:

```
"@apollo/client": "^3.3.7",
"subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.18",
"react": "^17.0.1"
```

```
const httpLink = new BatchHttpLink({ uri: config.API_URL })
const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: config.WS_URL,
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
    connectionParams:{       
      authToken: accessToken,
    },
  },
})

const splitLink = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query) 
    return definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' && definition.operation === 'subscription'
  },
  wsLink,
  httpLink
)
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: from([new SentryLink(), authLink, errorLink, splitLink]),
})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally found the solution. It turns out that you can declare a `SubscriptionClient` first and then insert this into `WebSocketLink`, rather than declare with `WebSocketLink` directly.

With SubscriptionClient, you can listen to the necessary events, whereas with `WebsocketLink` its not really possible(or very limited).

Unfortunately, no where in Apollo docs, mentions `SubscriptionClient` or ways of handling connection issues.

```
import { WebSocketLink } from '@apollo/client/link/ws'
import { SubscriptionClient } from 'subscriptions-transport-ws' // <- import this

const wsClient = new SubscriptionClient(config.WS_URL, {
  reconnect: true,
  connectionParams: {
    authToken: accessToken,
  },
})

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink(wsClient)
```

By doing so, now you can listen to connection events with `wsClient`

```
wsClient.onConnected(() => console.log("websocket connected!!"))
wsClient.onDisconnected(() => console.log("websocket disconnected!!"))
wsClient.onReconnected(() => console.log("websocket reconnected!!"))
```

There are more events you can listen to. But these events are sufficient to implement fetching missed chat messages.

With these events, after initial connection, you can store the `disconnectTimestamp` on disconnect event. When you receive `onReconnected` event, you can simply fetch chat messages that were created after the `disconnectTimestamp`

Comment: Note that `subscriptions-transport-ws` is the older, unmaintained library used for Apollo Client subscriptions: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/#choosing-a-subscription-library

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the option you'll want to use to target the WS connect/disconnect event is `connectionCallback` (see the full list of WebSocketLink options [here](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws/blob/master/src/client.ts#L61-L71)).

Take a look at [lines 620-635](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws/blob/8e042c96880a67aa3715c5a09d9b3ab5f2554885/src/client.ts#L620-L635) of the WebSocketLink source and you can see that the provided `connectionCallback` is called both for `GQL_CONNECTION_ERROR` and `GQL_CONNECTION_ACK` received message types. Therefore, you should be able to target both events using this callback.

I haven't used Apollo's WebSocketLink yet, So I am unable to confirm that this will work fully as expected. Additionally, the behavior to fetch all missing chat messages upon reconnect is something you may need to build yourself as it doesn't appear to be part of the default reconnect behavior (will depend on server implementation; see [Apollo Server docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#onconnect-and-ondisconnect)). Conversely, it does appear that WebSocketLink will forward all unsent messages to the server upon reconnect by default.

Comment: I tried connectionCallback and it does run when it establishes new connection, but it does not run when the websocket is disconnected. This is definitely an improvement, but ideally I would also like to know when it got disconencted, so that I can only fetch chat messages that occured during that period